# What should my GitHub SSH key be?

Tags: version-control, github, svn

I'm gettings started with GitHub and I have no clue what I'm doing.

What is an SSH key? What should I be setting as my key? Do I make it up?

**EDIT:**

I'm on OSX

Comment: They have detailed instructions online here, if you are on a *nix box: http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/

Comment: RTFM! http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Linux (or msysGit or Cygwin...):

1. Go to directory `~/.ssh`
2. Check if you already have this file: `id_rsa.pub`

   - If not, create it using this command: `ssh-keygen -C "name@email.com" -t rsa`
3. Get the content of this file (`cat id_rsa.pub`) and just copy and paste to GitHub.

That is it.

Comment: Also, make sure you have an extra copy of that key somewhere secure in case your harddisk fails on you.

Comment: Michiel Kalkman: There is **no need** to do that, copying your secure key from one harddrive to another breaks the idea of security. You can have more than one public keys in your GitHub account. If one ssh-key is compromised, such as from a harddrive failure or it's accidentally copied to a public location; you can always remove the key from GitHub, create a new one in your computer and upload the new public key to GitHub. This is why the public key usually ends with a comment on which `user@computer name` it was created from, in order to differentiate which key is used on which computer.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your first question:

For this purpose, think of SSH as a method of secure communication, using cryptography.

For most cryptographic algorithms, it would be necessary for you and GitHub to agree on a key separately, which is in generally impractical.  Therefore, SSH uses a class of cryptographic algorithms called "public key" or "asymmetric".

The idea is that you have two keys, such that what is encrypted by one is decrypted by the other, and it isn't computationally feasible to calculate one from the other.  There really weren't that many algorithms that worked, last I looked, but they existed.

Therefore, you have to generate the keys, randomly, and you call one your public key and one your private.  You send your public key to GitHub, or anybody else that wants it.  (Much of this is all handled automatically, given the right software.)  Then GitHub can send you information secretly by encrypting it with your public key, and only you can decrypt it.  GitHub will, similarly, send you a public key so you can send secret messages.

In practice, these ciphers are inefficient, so what you send back and forth is keys for efficient cryptographic algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux tips with ssh-keygen will most definitely work in OSX on the command line.  With that, Adriano's method should work fine. Remember to paste the pub key and not the other.